# How to correct create and pass object in first called constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have code:

```
UserDialog::UserDialog(DatabaseHandler &db,
                       QWidget *parent) :
    UserDialog{db, User(), parent}
{
}

UserDialog::UserDialog(DatabaseHandler &db, User &user, QWidget *parent):
    QDialog{parent},
    ui{new Ui::UserDialog},
    mDB{db},
    mUser{user}
{
    //...
}
```

How to correct create new User object and pass it as argument for calling constructor?

```
UserDialog{db, User(), parent}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `mUser` (and `mDB` while you're there)

Comment: It's here `User mUser;`

Comment: In that case I'd suggest fixing your problem by changing the parameter to `User const &user` .

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your constructor expects a mutable lvalue, you must provide an existing `User` object:

```
User user;
UserDialog{db, user, parent};
```

If the continued existence of the user object is not required, you can change the constructor parameter type to `const User&`, in which case a temporary will be accepted.

Comment: If `mUser` is a reference, this would be a mistake. (And if it's not a reference, then one would question the declaration of the parameter `user`)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I'll rewrite my constructor without temporary object because I cannot use `const User&`. I need to modify passed object when it will pass in second constructor (without first).

Comment: `mUser` isn't reference.

Comment: Well, then the purpose of your first constructor is unclear to me. If the constructor has to modify a given `User` object, then the first constructor seems to violate that somehow, because it has no notion of a `User` object. Maybe you need to rethink the purpose of your class?

Comment: Just when it calls second constructor directly it passes object with real ID, when it calls first constructor it passes empty object (object hasn't real ID).

Comment: I already write in comment that I try to migrate from java so I very bad know C++. I try to make first constructor as analog `public Constructor() {this(null);} public Constructor(User u) {mUser = u;}` but I don't know how to.

Comment: @ghostman: It seems you need pointer (which can be `nullptr`) instead of reference.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know for nullptr

Answer (score 1):

```
User user;
UserDialog{db, user, parent}
```

If you are passing a reference you need to create that reference before passing it.

Comment: I try to migrate from java so I think not like C++ programmer. It seems, I understand bug. Thank you!